# R. how to make matrix which have equal rows

Tags: r

I have row `f`. I want create matrix `R` such that every row of it is equal `f`.
What is the most efficient way to do it in R?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

with a row

```
f=c(1,22,33,44,55,66)
```

get its length

```
lf=length(f)
```

Then make the matrix

```
R=matrix(rep(f,lf),
         ncol=lf,
         byrow=T)
```

Gives:

```
R
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1   33   44   55   66
[2,]    1   33   44   55   66
[3,]    1   33   44   55   66
[4,]    1   33   44   55   66
[5,]    1   33   44   55   66
```

Answer (score 5):

```
R <-  matrix(f, 1)[rep(1,n), ]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

Or even more compact:

```
R <- rbind(f)[rep(1,n), ]
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
f    1    2    3    4    5
f    1    2    3    4    5
f    1    2    3    4    5
f    1    2    3    4    5
f    1    2    3    4    5
```

Note that rownames of matrices do not need to be unique, unlike the case with data.frames.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possibility:

```
mymat <- do.call( rbind, rep(list(f), 10) )
```