# r: how to make matrix multiplication faster (special case)

Tags: r

I want to have a matrix d3 (m x n) whose each row is identical and equal to a given vector (d0) with dimension n.

My try was the following:
Let

```
 m=1000
 n=20000
 d0=runif(n)
 d1=diag(d0)
 d2=array(1,dim=c(m,n)).
```

I would like to compute the product of the above two matrix, d3, where

```
 d3=d2%*%d1.
```

This straightforward way of matrix multiplication is very slow. How to make multiplication faster in the above special case? Thanks.

Comment: in this special case, you could just write `d3 <- d2`

Comment: can you say more about the actual constraints of your problem?  as @HubertL points out, if `d1` is the identity matrix then you're done. Is `d1`  in reality a diagonal matrix with entries other than 1 on the diagonal? In that case I think `sweep(d2,diag(d1),MARGIN=2,FUN="*")` would work ...

Comment: @BenBolker. The actual constraint my problem was a diagonal matrix with entries other than 1. I corrected this point in my question. Thank you Prof.

Comment: @HubertL. Thanks for your comments. I corrected my question and posted the actual problem.

Comment: @BenBolker Your suggested code is 43 time faster than my code. This is very useful to my problem.

Comment: I found much faster solutions for the above problem  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867221/r-how-to-make-matrix-which-have-equal-rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to have a matrix d3 (m x n) whose each row is identical and
>   equal to a given vector (d0) with dimension n.

This is trivial to do using the `matrix` function and vector recycling.

```
m=4
n=5
set.seed(42)
d0=runif(n)
matrix(d0, nrow = m, ncol = n, byrow = TRUE)
#         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 0.914806 0.9370754 0.2861395 0.8304476 0.6417455
#[2,] 0.914806 0.9370754 0.2861395 0.8304476 0.6417455
#[3,] 0.914806 0.9370754 0.2861395 0.8304476 0.6417455
#[4,] 0.914806 0.9370754 0.2861395 0.8304476 0.6417455
```

This should be the fastest solution.

Comment: I missed the trivial trick. This is the fasted one. Thanks for the answer.